# cannot read property email of undefined when i try to access session data in my NodeJs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

Basically, When i run this code, It is displaying  that it cannot read property of undefined email. I need this project to work in such a way that i will be able to display the email value from the login page.

```js
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
// accept url encoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));


// accept json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
var router=express.Router();
router.get('/',function (req,res) {
   if(!session.req.email){
       res.send('email not set');
   } else{
       res.send('welcome'+session.req.email+': We love you');
   }
});

router.get('/login',function (req,res) {
    res.render('login');
});

router.post('/login',urlencodedParser,function (req,res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    session.req.email=req.body.email;
    session.req.email=req.body.email;
});
app.use(router);
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You should post the code inside your question, so it is impossible to know what you have done. Please edit your question and add the code that is causing you problems.

Comment: I have done exactly that. Please check again and see if you can assist me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

const port = 8000;

app.set('port', process.env.port || port);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'))
app.set('view_engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));


 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if (!req.session.email) {
    res.send('email not set');
   } else {
   res.send('welcome' + req.session.email + ': We love you');
  }
 });

 app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  res.render('login');
 });

 app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
  req.session.email = req.body.email;
  req.session.email = req.body.email;
 });

 app.listen(port, console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`))
```

Update your code and it will work for you.

Comment: can you update your code there is code that is redundant so it will be easy to understand it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need everywhere in your code to replace `session.req.email` with `req.session.email` the user session is actually attached to his request.

Your code has many duplications, also please notice if you submit the form using ajax you need to provide a header content-type that is suitable with the serialization data you provide for example:

1- as **JSON**

```
fetch("/login", {
  method: "POST", 
 headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({email:"digital.flowers@hotmail.com"})
})
```

or

2- as **encoded url**

```
fetch("/login", {
      method: "POST", 
     headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: "email=digital.flowers@hotmail.com"
    })
```

here is the final form of your code after some cleaning, the code is tested and it's working for me:

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// parsers
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
//app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

// router
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.session.email) {
        res.send('email not set');
    } else {
        res.send('welcome' + req.session.email + ': We love you');
    }
});

router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});

router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    req.session.email = req.body.email;
    res.send("ok");
});
app.use(router);

// server
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```